# Keeping a fixed div a specific distance from another div even when resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically want the navigation div to be say 50px from the right edge of the picture but it needs to be fixed so that when you scroll it still remains at the location. Basically, as the image gets resized with the browser, the nav should keep a permanent relation of 50px to the image. I'm just not sure how to go about doing this with a fixed div.

```
#wrapperNav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 45%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 200px;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/LLtnZ/

Comment: It's important to use a placeholder in your fiddle so it actually shows an image

Comment: add your `wrapperNav` div to `item` div. Add to `item` css `position:relative;` add to `wrapperNav` css : `{position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px; right: 50px;
z-index:999;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the position of the nav on window resize.

**JS**

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
    var gutter_space = 55;
    var left_pos =  ($('.item img').outerWidth() + $('.item img').offset().left) - gutter_space;    
   $('#wrapperNav').css('left',left_pos); 
})
```

Use `left` position instead of right.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/LLtnZ/2/)

**UPDATE**: Equal spacing

JS

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
           var left_width =  ($('.item img').outerWidth() + $('.item img').offset().left);
           var gap = ($(window).outerWidth() - left_width); 
           var right_pos =  (gap - $('#wrapperNav').width())/2; //Space to be left on each side of the nav.
           $('#wrapperNav').css('right',right_pos); 
    });
```

Also update your css, for demo purpose gave width to the `#wrapperNav`

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/LLtnZ/7/)

Comment: Is there a way so that the spacing from the img to the nav to the right side of the page are both equal?   [img]  nav  |right

Comment: I did not understand your question, but you an change the value of the  `gutter_space` variable to adjust the position of the nav. Or just describe your requirement in an image..

Comment: sorry I meant like can the script be written so that the nav takes into account the distance of it from image and at the same time the distance of it from the right edge of the viewport so that both distances are equal all the time, meaning the nav sits directly in the middle between the image and the right side of the viewport.

Comment: According to what I understood have update the code. See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the question, but I took a crack at it. Is this similar to what you were asking?

http://jsfiddle.net/LLtnZ/1/

```
var moveNav = function(left){
    $('#wrapperNav').css({'left': left});
};

moveNav( $('.item:visible').width() + 50 );

$(window).on('resize', function(left){
    var img = $('.item:visible');
    var imgWidth = img.width();
    moveNav(imgWidth + 50);
});
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if thats headed in the right direction.